# I need help understanding ruby's floating point precision

Tags: ruby, floating-point-precision, fixnum

I came across this the other day and sure its not causing me any trouble but i'm just curious as to why it happens?

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > 0.39-0.09
 => 0.30000000000000004
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Ruby by default uses [Double-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). You can read about issues related to it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). However here's a short and crisp answer:

> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

Source: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You may want to use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to avoid such problems.